# "The numbness and chill contracted by sixteen hours’ exposure" from "Jane Eyre"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a question about the following extract from the novel "[Jane Eyre](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/b/bronte/charlotte/b869j/chapter11.html)":

> A new chapter in a novel is something like a new scene in a play; and when I draw up the curtain this time, reader, you must fancy you see a room in the George Inn at Millcote, with such large figured papering on the walls as inn rooms have; such a carpet, such furniture, such ornaments on the mantelpiece, such prints, including a portrait of George the Third, and another of the Prince of Wales, and a representation of the death of Wolfe. All this is visible to you by the light of an oil lamp hanging from the ceiling, and by that of an excellent fire, near which I sit in my cloak and bonnet; my muff and umbrella lie on the table, and I am warming away the numbness and chill contracted by sixteen hours’ exposure to the rawness of an October day: I left Lowton at four o’clock a.m., and the Millcote town clock is now just striking eight.

Specifically what is the meaning of the word **contract** in the clause:

> "and I am warming away the numbness and chill **contracted** by sixteen hours’ exposure to the rawness of an October day"

I looked up the word "contract" in the Oxford Dictionaries, but I can't determine which meaning of the word is used in the sentence.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contract

Comment: **(3)** [WITH OBJECT] Catch or develop (a disease or infectious agent):
'*three people contracted a killer virus*'

Answer (score 3):

It is definition 3 from your [Oxford dictionaries link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contract):

> (3) [WITH OBJECT] Catch or develop (a disease or infectious agent): *'three people contracted a killer virus'*

She *developed* a numbness and chill by being outside for sixteen hours in October.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @LiXiaodong - No problem. In future, do consider this site over English.SE if you have basic comprehension questions.

Comment: Yes and Jane Eyre's no spring chicken. 

Modern usage would be 'contracted from (or through)' or 'caused by…'